# Hover Disabled after Waypoint Event

Tags: jquery, css, hover, nav, jquery-waypoints

I have set both a sprite hover event and waypoint Jquery events that change the css depending on the anchor/scroll on my main nav menu -

jfiddle example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/LhLpm39p/17/

```
$('#news').waypoint(function (direction) {
if (direction === 'up') {

    $('#news-menu').css({
        "background-position": "0 0",
            "color": "#fff"
    });


}
}, {
offset: '100%'
}).waypoint(function (direction) {
if (direction === 'down') {

    $('#news-menu').css({
        "background-position": "0 100%",
            "color": "#00a4f0"
    });

}
}, {
offset: '50%'
}).waypoint(function (direction) {
if (direction === 'down') {

    $('#news-menu').css({
        "background-position": "0 0",
            "color": "#fff"
    });

}
}, {
offset: '0%'

});
```

The hover works fine before you click on any of the navs, but once you click on one and trigger the waypoint the hover becomes disabled!

How do I rectify this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one of CSS Specificity issue. Just decorate with `!important`. This should resolve issue:

```
.menu:hover {
    background: url("http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/two/950x350/950x350-vegas-gold-venetian-red-two-color-background.jpg") 0 100%!important;
color: #00a4f0!important;
}
```